# Converter VARCHAR para TIMESTAMP (AWS REDSHIFT/POSTGRESQL)

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, postgresql, amazon-aws

Tenho o seguinte problema, na origem tenho os dados vindo como varchar

exemplo de dados da origem em formato varchar:

- 08:15:49
- 18:16:05
- 20:01:33

etc...

preciso reinserir esses dados em uma nova tabela para isso fiz um insert com o seguinte select

```
INSERT INTO NOVA_TABELA(
    NOVO_CAMPO
)
SELECT  
    TO_TIMESTAMP(hora, 'HH24:MI:SS') 
FROM TABELA_ANTIGA;
```

O problema é que eu preciso apenas da hora, e o timestamp está adicionando data ao lado da hora

saída da transformação:

- 0001-01-01 08:15:49
- 0001-01-01 18:16:05
- 0001-01-01 20:01:33

Quero que apenas converta a string da origem para time sem adicionar nada, porém não estou conseguindo...

Answer (score 1):

A função de conversão [`TO_TIMESTAMP()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/functions-formatting.html) retorna o tipo [`TIMESTAMP`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html). Você precisa usar um [`CAST`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS) para o tipo [`TIME`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html) a fim de converter os dados, veja só:

```
TO_TIMESTAMP( hora, 'HH24:MI:SS' )::TIME
```

No seu caso:

```
INSERT INTO NOVA_TABELA(
    NOVO_CAMPO
)
SELECT  
    TO_TIMESTAMP(hora, 'HH24:MI:SS')::TIME 
FROM TABELA_ANTIGA;
```

Vamos a um exemplo prático, assumindo que sua tabela de origem seja algo como:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_origem
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  hora VARCHAR(8)
);

INSERT INTO tb_origem ( id, hora ) VALUES ( 1, '08:15:49' );
INSERT INTO tb_origem ( id, hora ) VALUES ( 2, '18:16:05' );
INSERT INTO tb_origem ( id, hora ) VALUES ( 3, '20:01:33' );
```

E sua tabela de destino:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_destino
(
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  hora TIME
);
```

Você pode converter um `VARCHAR` para `TIME` da seguinte forma:

```
INSERT INTO tb_destino (id, hora )
(SELECT id, to_timestamp( hora, 'HH24:MI:SS' )::time FROM tb_origem);
```

Veja funcionando no [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/d9005/2)

Comment: considerando o dado de entrada, não é mais simples só fazer o cast direto `hora::time`? Ou, pra ficar dentro do padrão ANSI SQL,  `CAST(hora as time)`?